# Should I put a cap on this pipe?

Tags: plumbing

Underneath my kitchen sink you can see the following:

[image: plumbing]

As you can see, the spout (is this the correct term?) has kitchen roll stuck in it.

Isn't this suppose to be sealed with a cap? Doesn't it run the risk of leaking (granted it hasn't just yet). If it does need a cap what should I be getting for it?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Further pictures for clarity.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like there was once (perhaps) a dishwasher installed, improperly... and possibly still improperly. It has a chance to leak if the pipe backs up, before it backs up into the sink basin it will go onto the floor. It looks like there is a connection on the back as well.... is that a dishwasher? cant tell what is also up top, larger hose, a washer? More photos will help, and a description of everything draining here too.

Comment: Hi @noybman. I pulled the dishwasher out last week as we weren't using it and it wasn't in the best condition. It actually attached to a similar nozzle that was on the pipe on the left. The only thing that drains into the pipes now are the washing machine and the sink. I'll take a couple more photos and edit my question.

Comment: what is the point of posting more photos? ... clearly, if you get a clog in the trap below, or further downstream, the sink or dishwasher will drain onto the floor .... take the picture to a hardware store and show it to the sales staff and ask for a cap

Comment: @jsotola the point is to verify if it requires a cap and, if it does, what to get. Forgive me if my plumbing experience isn't as developed as yours.

Comment: i do not have much plumbing experience, however i know how water behaves ... i am certain that you also know how water behaves ... so the answer to the question whether you need a cap is obvious ... that is why i said to take the picture to a hardware store for assistance

Comment: I was asting the question for more photos to provide a more helpful answer because capping it while absolutely necessary to keep water off the floor, I would anticipate he doesn't want water backing up into the washer or the dishwasher. It looks like there are two dishwasher style fittings in addition to the washer. It's ahrd to tell if the loops are high enough to promote water to backup into the sink. Also, he has no air gap for the washer that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

That is one option. A better option may be to replace the double-wye with a single wye and eliminate unnecessary potential future leak sources. The wye on the left is no longer needed. The fewer the joints, the fewer potential failure points.